Can Atreides' sonic weapons penetrate the Holtzman shield?
In Lynch's Dune, House Atreides secretly developed sonic weapons and trained elite troopers to use them. The emperor feared of Atreides' sonic weapons and therefore conspired with House Harkonnen to destroy them on Arrakis.
The Holtzman shield is a personal defensive force field based on the "Holtzman effect". It can deflect fast-moving objects like bullets and is very dangerous (to both sides) against energy/laser weapons.
Can Atreides' sonic weapons penetrate the Holtzman shield and hurt the person protected by the shield?

Where did you get this idea? The concept of the sonic weapons, and that being the reason why the Emperor turned on the Atreides, comes from the Lynch film. No other version - and certainly not the books - has this as a motivation.

@DanielRoseman - So, can they in the Lynch film?

I can't find a clip but I'm pretty sure we see Fremen armed with the weirding modules beat Sardaukar with shields.

@DanielRoseman - That would make a solid answer.

@DanielRoseman But is the shield not used on Arrakis because it attracts sandworms?

@Triceratops Worms were not and could not be present in the region within the Shield Wall, until Paul made a hole in it.

There is no scene in Lynch's Dune of the "sonic weapons" being used on shields. Only aircraft, harvesters and unshielded ground troops.

@Paulie_D that sounds like an answer to me

We don't know as there is no evidence either way.
Simply, there is no scene in Lynch's Dune of the "sonic weapons" being used on shields. Only aircraft, harvesters and unshielded ground troops are targeted with the weirding module weapons.
